# How to understand the opcode of AzerothCore?

Tags: opcode, azerothcore

I've been study the opcode of  AzerothCore, there a lot of opcodes like below:

```
CMSG_ZONE_MAP
CMSG_CREATEITEM
CMSG_CREATEGAMEOBJECT
CMSG_PETGODMODE
```

Could you pls help me understand how it works and how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The opcode is some specific part of the packets data which depends on the client, so you cannot change them, they are strictly related to the client.

Depends on the client version 1.x, 2.4.3, etc. these opcodes change.